# vb.Net Writing Better Code with Progress Updates During Execution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Hello stack**overflow** geniuses! I have learned much from seeking answers on this site and am very grateful for its existence. I am a novice (at best) and completely self taught when it comes to programming. Google taught is probably more accurate. Never the less, I always seek to become better and code daily. Here is my latest query:

I am writing a vb.net Windows Forms application that takes images and creates a few thumbnails for them in their corresponding directories. For the most part I have made this code work, but there are a few things I would like to make better.

## 1

I would like the application to give a real time progress bar update as it progresses through the images. Currently I am using a For Loop, so I am not sure how that even works. I don't think I have ever really understood how programs give updates without trying to give all the information at once like For Loops seem to do.

## 2

Performance. What could I do to make it run more efficient and faster?

## 3

I am working on trying to create thumbnails that retain aspect ratios and insert the new (smaller image) into the re-sized canvas. I am fairly confident I can figure this out, but just wanted to add this as a process feature in case it becomes relevant to doing the real time progress updates.

Here is my code as it is displayed in the btnRun click handler:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class fmMain

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim path As String = tbPath.Text
    Dim pathL As String
    Dim pathF As String = Application.StartupPath() & "\done"

    For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(tbRange.Text)

        path = tbPath.Text
        pathF = Application.StartupPath() & "\done"

        x = i
        s = x.ToString

        Dim a(s.Length) As String

        For j As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
            a(j) = s.Substring(j, 1)
            path += "\" & a(j)
        Next

        pathL = path
        path += "\" & s & ".jpg"

        If File.Exists(path) Then

            pbMain.Image = Image.FromFile(path)

            Dim bmp As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(path)

            ' bmpt is the new thumb
            Dim bmpHome As New Bitmap(124, 124)
            Dim bmpLarge As New Bitmap(256, 256)
            Dim bmpMedium As New Bitmap(58, 58)
            Dim bmpSmall As New Bitmap(45, 45)
            Dim bmpThick As New Bitmap(600, 600)

            ' DRAW HOME
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpHome)

                ' bmp == the original bitmap 
                g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpHome.Width + 1, bmpHome.Height + 1)

            End Using

            ' DRAW LARGE
            Using L As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpLarge)

                ' bmp == the original bitmap 
                L.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpLarge.Width + 1, bmpLarge.Height + 1)

            End Using

            ' DRAW MEDIUM
            Using M As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpMedium)

                ' bmp == the original bitmap 
                M.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpMedium.Width + 1, bmpMedium.Height + 1)

            End Using

            ' DRAW SMALL
            Using SM As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpSmall)

                ' bmp == the original bitmap 
                SM.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpSmall.Width + 1, bmpSmall.Height + 1)

            End Using

            ' DRAW THICK
            Using T As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpThick)

                ' bmp == the original bitmap 
                T.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpThick.Width + 1, bmpThick.Height + 1)

            End Using

            For p As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
                a(p) = s.Substring(p, 1)
                pathF += "\" & a(p)

                If Not File.Exists(pathF) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathF)
                End If

            Next

            bmp.Save(pathF & "\" & s & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmpHome.Save(pathF & "\" & s & "-home_default.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmpLarge.Save(pathF & "\" & s & "-large_default.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmpMedium.Save(pathF & "\" & s & "-medium_default.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmpSmall.Save(pathF & "\" & s & "-small_default.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bmpThick.Save(pathF & "\" & s & "-thickbox_default.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

            bmp.Dispose()
            bmpHome.Dispose()
            bmpLarge.Dispose()
            bmpSmall.Dispose()
            bmpThick.Dispose()

        End If

    Next

    MessageBox.Show("All Done!")
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100

End Sub
End Class
```

I am here to learn so any advice, tips, or links would be extremely appreciated and helpful. As always thank you for taking a look at my question and code. I can only hope to one day be seasoned enough to answer questions others my have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to split up your original post (OP) to get all the answers.

1) is about how to use a progress bar: Set the .Maximum to the number of files to process, inside the FOR..LOOP increment the .Value. Reset the .Value at some point - maybe when finished or at least during the next button click.

2) you may want to look for other tags to increase chances of a good reply

3) seems redundant

Comment: For the progress bar bit, I found that executing Application.DoEvents() during each cycle made the bar and other label elements update. I ended up using 2 variables, one for the increment ammount (is if you have 80k loops to run dividing into 100 as an integer wont work), and then another that looks for the value to be an integer. Then add to the progress bar. It actually worked nicely! That being said, using the .Maximum would have been a hell of a lot easier and I will try that in the future! Thank you! I will try and break this up a bit as I always have MANY questions.